# How to maintain Truncate logs in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit-logging

I have a stored procedure which truncate all tables of my database. I want to trace the truncate for each table. So that if it fails somewhere, I could see where it is stopped and which tables are truncated successfully.

I created an Audit but it's for a single database. I don't know how to create an Audit for all databases.

Comment: AFAIK Truncate table is not logged...

Comment: Is there an alternative ? As i have to keep record of which tables are truncated successfully

Answer (score 0):

you can create DDL triggers, Hope it can fulfil your requirement.